# MATLAB idnlgrey multidimensional pem: parallelization

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to do a parameter estimation of a nonlinear multidimensional dynamical model specified as an `idnlgrey` object. In particular, i'm using the `'lsqnonlin'` estimator with the `pem` function.

I'm satisfied both with accuracy and performance when fitting a model which is up to 8 dimensions.

The problem with performance starts arising as long as the dimensionality grows (my objective whould be scaling up to some hundreds of dimensions).

From the documentation I wasn't able to have a clear idea on whether pem itself can be run in parallel, nor it is clear if it can be considered a memory or CPU bound function. 
I wonder if I can take advantage of the parallelization toolbox.